# Saving Form Submission to CSV file

Tags: php

Hi I'm getting a syntax error with this code, i'm trying to save the results of a form to a csv file. the error is on the $savestring line ... Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in /home/blahblah/public_html/forms/ContactUs/includes/contact.php on line 24

I can't see what I have done wrong, can anyone point out my error?

```
{
$customername = $_POST['CustomerName'];
$companyname = $_POST['CompanyName'];
$noemps = $_POST['NoEmps'];
$telephone = $_POST['TelephoneNo'];
$email = $_POST['EmailAddress'];
$addressline1 = $_POST['AddressLine1'];
$addressline2 = $_POST['AddressLine2'];
$addressline3 = $_POST['AddressLine3'];
$city = $_POST['City'];
$county = $_POST['County'];
$postcode = $_POST['PostCode'];
$enquiry = $_POST['Enquiry'];
$upload = $_POST['upload'];
$source = $_POST['Source'];
$quotecode = $_POST['QuoteCode'];


$fp = fopen(”ContactUs.csv”, “a”);
$savestring = $customername . “,” . $companyname . "," . $noemps . "," . $telephone .     "," . $email . ",“ . $addressline1 . "," . $addressline2 . "," . $addressline3 . "," . $city . "," . $county . "," . $postcode . "," . $enquiry . "," . $upload . "," . $source . "," .$qoutecode . "\n”;
fwrite($fp, $savestring);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: stop using word for code! so called smart quotes are borking it

Comment: You h ave some non-standard double quotes there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to declare a string with a special character (`“`).

Try changing this:

```
$customername . “,” . $companyname
```

To this:

```
$customername . "," . $companyname
```

In addition, there are three more:

1) `”ContactUs.csv”, “a”` => `"ContactUs.csv", "a"`

2) `$email . ",“ . $addressline1` => `$email . "," . $addressline1`

3) `" .$qoutecode . "\n”` => `" .$qoutecode . "\n"`

Therefore, your new code will be:

```
{
$customername = $_POST['CustomerName'];
$companyname = $_POST['CompanyName'];
$noemps = $_POST['NoEmps'];
$telephone = $_POST['TelephoneNo'];
$email = $_POST['EmailAddress'];
$addressline1 = $_POST['AddressLine1'];
$addressline2 = $_POST['AddressLine2'];
$addressline3 = $_POST['AddressLine3'];
$city = $_POST['City'];
$county = $_POST['County'];
$postcode = $_POST['PostCode'];
$enquiry = $_POST['Enquiry'];
$upload = $_POST['upload'];
$source = $_POST['Source'];
$quotecode = $_POST['QuoteCode'];


$fp = fopen("ContactUs.csv", "a");
$savestring = $customername . "," . $companyname . "," . $noemps . "," . $telephone .     "," . $email . "," . $addressline1 . "," . $addressline2 . "," . $addressline3 . "," . $city . "," . $county . "," . $postcode . "," . $enquiry . "," . $upload . "," . $source . "," .$qoutecode . "\n";
fwrite($fp, $savestring);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: And this `"\n”;` to this `"\n";`

Comment: Oh true.  I think I'm just going to do a find on the whole code and make sure I have them all.

Comment: Hey thanks, I'm just using code anywhere and " are coming out funny!!? not sure why? you fixed it though and I now now to look out for that.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is right here:

```
",“
```

Do you see the minute difference in quotes? That's causing the first quote, the valid one, to remain open.

As a side comment, you're using " quotes so by default you're telling the interpreter to parse all strings for variables, so the constant concats you're doing are pointless. Just putting the variables directly into a single string will work fine.

Answer (score -1):

Try in this way

```
$list = array (
    array('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'dddd'),
    array('123', '456', '789'),
    array('"aaa"', '"bbb"')
);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: This works, but see if you can't put it in the context of his original question.

Comment: @Zarathuztra: No it doesn't, that example opens the file for `Write` and not `Append`

Comment: @PeteR Correct, that's why I say it's not in the context of the original question.